# How to add username and image on right of navbar using bootstarp

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap , how can i add name and image in right of navbar as shown in image. On hovering of image logout should be display, how can i do it using bootstrap in mvc project

Comment: Can you attach your HTML code?

Comment: I have not write code

Answer (score 3):

**Refer to [bootstrap navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)**

Below is a demo:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            UserName &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <img class="img-thumbnail rounded-circle" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/img%20(30).jpg">
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav>
    ...
    <span class="float-right">
        UserName
        <img class="img-thumbnail rounded-circle" src="..." alt="">
    </span>
</nav>
```